# How to call IObjectExporter::ServerAlive2 in Windows COM

Tags: windows, com

I have looked up a lot of information(include MSDN), but there was no clear example of how to use it

Answer (score 0):

Solved, there are so many details. See https://github.com/EddieIvan01/win32api-practice/tree/master/oxid-nic-resolver